# Why Google reCAPTCHA asking for subdomain?

Tags: google-app-engine, recaptcha

I want to use google recaptcha but google asking for subdomain. I have no subdomain. But I want to use google recaptcha.

How can I use google recaptcha?

Comment: not really: http://i.imgur.com/Tt01WXe.png

Answer (score 0):

if your using a free webhosting site:

> use their domain name, like what i did on a test site on aspspider.com
>
> i registered `aspspider.ws`

if you have a registered domain, but dont have subdomain:

> just use that, like: `panda.com`

if you just want to test on localhost, just use any domain name or a domain name you would likely use when you put your site online, all keys work on localhost

that should be sufficient.